# buffer null termination

Tags: c

I am trying to add a null termination to my buffer with the following code. But I don't seem to be able to pass my null terminator in.Is this the correct way to do it? When I strlen my buffer the value is 10 but I only keyed in 9 chars.

```
char buffer[256];
int n;

bzero(buffer,256);
fgets(buffer,255,stdin);
buffer[n-1]="\0";
```

Comment: Did you count the newline among the 9 chars? And `n` is uninitialised.

Comment: its either ommited or missing something along the lines of `n = something`.

Comment: `fgets()` atomatically adds the terminating `'\0'`.

Comment: Note that `"\0"` and `'\0'` are different things!

Comment: Thanks Alot. I didn't realise i was actually terminating as string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are assigning a string not a char with
`buffer[n-1] = "\0";`.
Try 
`buffer[n-1] = '\0';` 
instead.

Comment: and initialize the variable `n` ;)

Comment: Yeah and as someone said: Don't forget to set your n variable, or preferably skip it and use a `#define BUFFER_SIZE 256` instead of hardcoded values. Dont use `bzero` its deprecated, use `memset`.

Comment: Yes, what's *n* by the way?

Comment: I was hoping he just left that part of the code out, otherwise for sure!

Comment: The `buffer[x] = "\0";` line should show a pretty scary warning *assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast*

Comment: Apparently that warning isn't scary enough, considering how often people ignore it. I don't understand why gcc hasn't changed that warning into a mandatory error. It's a constraint violation and a compiler is perfectly justified in rejecting it.

Comment: Yes. i saw the warning but i just ignore it. Didn't know the warning was somehow connected.

Answer (score 0):

You're right-hand value has the wrong type (`char *` when something that converts to `char` is needed).

The proper way is:

```
buffer[n - 1] = '\0';
```

This can just as well be written:

```
buffer[n - 1] = 0;
```

but the first one makes it clear we're dealing with characters. I assume `n` is set somewhere, too.

If `buffer` is an array and you want to make sure it's last character is set to zero, you can use:

```
buffer[sizeof buffer - 1] = '\0';
```

This uses the `sizeof` operator to avoid repeating constants and such. Note that it only works if `buffer` is a proper array, if all you have is a pointer (`char *buffer;`) it won't do the expected thing.

Comment: yes. my n is set to read the buffer. i tried using sizeof but i got expected identifier in front of sizeof. so i didn't move on with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
char buffer[256] = {'\0' };
```

fixes your issue.